# find error message contain particular substring with wildcard

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one error message like following, How can I use assert to make sure the error message contains "Element is not clickable"?
I have tried but it does not work

```
assert getattr(e, 'message', str(e)) == "Element * is not clickable at point"
```

`Message: unknown error: Element <i class="dropdown"></i> is not clickable at point (860, 345). Other element would receive the click: <div class="field">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 75 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
Session ID: 026bc5877b6f98f4ccb50fecb690a941
Screenshot: available via screen`

Comment: You could use regular expressions.

Comment: `assert re.search("Element .*? is not clickable at point", getattr(e, 'message', str(e)))`